# Connecting to Android 4.4 phone itself (localhost) when in airplane mode

Tags: android, nanohttpd

My Android App is running it's own webserver on port 24783.

I can connect to it when I'm in my local wireless. I enter the local wifi ip and the port in the phones chrome browser and the website appears. However, when I'm offline (but the server is running locally on my phone), I can't connect to 127.0.0.1:24783 and additionally when I'm only connected over 4G I can not connect to 127.0.0.1:24783 either because all traffic goes over my carriers proxy and wont allow me to connect on 127.0.0.1

Is there a way to tell the phone that for 127.0.0.1 it should not talk to the proxy? That 127.0.0.1 is always "local"? I'm happy to use my own webview.

**UPDATE:**

Turns out this is only a KitKat issue.

I haven't found a solution but go a bit closer.

The solution bellow only works when I open the app, close it using the back button and reopen it again:

```
package com.ndream.console;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Proxy;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.ArrayMap;
import android.util.Log;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

/**
 * Created by andrin on 15/01/15.
 */
public class ProxyUtils {
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public static void setKitKatWebViewProxy(Context appContext, String host, int port) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT != 19) {
            return;
        }
        Log.i("Console", "PROXY MANUALLY SET");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", host);
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", port + "");
        System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", host);
        System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", port + "");
        try {
            Class applictionCls = Class.forName("android.app.Application");
            Field loadedApkField = applictionCls.getDeclaredField("mLoadedApk");
            loadedApkField.setAccessible(true);
            Object loadedApk = loadedApkField.get(appContext);
            Class loadedApkCls = Class.forName("android.app.LoadedApk");
            Field receiversField = loadedApkCls.getDeclaredField("mReceivers");
            receiversField.setAccessible(true);
            ArrayMap receivers = (ArrayMap) receiversField.get(loadedApk);
            for (Object receiverMap : receivers.values()) {
                for (Object rec : ((ArrayMap) receiverMap).keySet()) {
                    Class clazz = rec.getClass();
                    if (clazz.getName().contains("ProxyChangeListener")) {
                        Method onReceiveMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("onReceive", Context.class, Intent.class);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Proxy.PROXY_CHANGE_ACTION);

                        /*********** optional, may be need in future *************/
                        final String CLASS_NAME = "android.net.ProxyProperties";
                        Class cls = Class.forName(CLASS_NAME);
                        Constructor constructor = cls.getConstructor(String.class, Integer.TYPE, String.class);
                        constructor.setAccessible(true);
                        Object proxyProperties = constructor.newInstance(host, port, null);
                        intent.putExtra("proxy", (Parcelable) proxyProperties);
                        /*********** optional, may be need in future *************/

                        onReceiveMethod.invoke(rec, appContext, intent);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and then on startup I call:

```
ProxyUtils.setKitKatWebViewProxy(getApplicationContext(), "", 0);
```

Comment: did you try replacing 127.0.0.1 with 10.0.2.2?

Comment: @waqaslam: 10.0.2.2 is for connecting to the host computer when android is running in an emulator. We do not want to connect to the host computer. We want to connect to the webserver running on the phone.